# Como criar um Cron job?

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel

Tenho um site de imobiliária que todo dia fazemos uma importação de um XML dos imóveis adicionados no dia anterior. Essa importação é feita por um componente em que escolho o arquivo e dou importar e ele roda a função.

Editei o componente para ao invés de escolher o arquivo, já pegar direto de um arquivo que está sempre disponível com o mesmo nome (ex: www.site.com.br/imoveis.xml), atualizando os dados do XML automaticamente todos os dias.

Não tenho experiência nenhuma com cron jobs, como faço para criar um agendamento para todo dia ele fazer essa importação? Ou pelo menos, o caminho para eu fazer isso.

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional do servidor? Você tem acesso de shell/SSH a ele?

Comment: é linux, o acesso que tenho é cpanel que tem trabalhos cron. o que consegui fazer é acessar uma url especifica, que se logar, ele funcoina certinho, mas não consegui fazer ele logar sozinho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de fazer isso é:

1. Definir o que o cron vai fazer, o que vai manipular, seja no banco de dados ou em arquivos do servidor.
2. Criar/testar scripts com as rotinas e funções que façam as manipulações que foram definidas inicialmente. Exemplo: Criar rotinas que leiam o XML disponível e atualizem os valores no banco de dados.
3. CRON:
   Para criar uma tarefa agendada, faça o seguinte:

Clique no botão "Cron Jobs" ícone dentro *cPanel*, em Avançados.
Verifique se o endereço de e-mail atual é válido. Caso contrário, digite um novo e-mail e clique no botão "Atualizar E-mail".

Selecione a configuração que você deseja.

Alternativamente, você pode ajustar as definições de tempo individualmente. Minuto, hora, dia, mês e dia da semana pode ser modificado para atingir seu objetivo.

Na caixa de entrada à direita de "Command, digite o nome" do tipo de arquivo, em seguida, adicione um espaço e forneça o caminho para o arquivo que você deseja que o comando a ser executado.(Link do seu script)

Clique no botão "Add New Cron Job".
Você acabou de criar um cron job para executar um arquivo em uma determinada data e hora com a repetição desejado.

Tarefas Agendadas são fáceis de editar e apagar.
Clique no botão "Cron Jobs" dentro do cPanel.
Desça até a última seção chamada "Cron Jobs Atuais".
Encontre o cron job correto e clique em "Editar" ou "Delete", no âmbito das ações.
Edição não tem boas ferramentas automatizadas, por isso pode ser mais fácil copiar o comando, o trabalho do cron apagar e recriar.

Criação em linhas de comando. Apenas exemplos! seções em negrito devem ser alterados.

**PHP**

*Comando para executar um trabalho cron PHP 5.5:*

```
/opt/php55/bin/php/home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo.php
```

*Comando para executar um trabalho cron PHP 5.4:*

```
/opt/php54/bin/php/home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo.php
```

*Comando para executar um trabalho cron PHP 5.3:*

```
/opt/php53/bin/php/home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo.php
```

*Sinalizador opcional às vezes necessário para um trabalho do cron PHP:*

```
php -q /home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo. php
```

*Comando para usar um arquivo php.ini específico:*

```
php -c /home/USUARIO/public_html/php.ini /home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo.php
```

*Comando para obter um arquivo remoto:*

```
/usr/bin/GET http://www.seudomini....br/arquivo.php
```

*Comando para executar um trabalho cron CGI:*

```
/home/perl/USUARIO/public_html/cgi-bin/arquivo.pl
```

**SSH Extras**

*Comando para executar um trabalho cron shell script:*

```
/bin/sh/home/USUARIO/public_html/arquivo.sh
```

*Comando para importar um banco de dados:*

```
mysql -u mysql_user -p senha database_name < backup.sql
```

*Comando para exportar um banco de dados:*

```
mysqldump -u mysql_user -p senha database_name > backup.sql
```

Fontes:

http://forum.hostgator.com.br/topic/241-criar-e-excluir-um-trabalho-cron/
http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: Legal, ja me deu uma luz! Agora o que preciso é montar o php que faça o trabalho. preciso que o cron acesse o link que faz a tarefa (dominio.com/administrator/importar.xml). só que esse link só pode ser acessado pelo admin, é possivel no proprio cron passar login e senha pra ele acessar?

Comment: Talvez(possivelmente) nem seja preciso forçar um login pelo código, você só precisa acessar os arquivos e diretorios e trabalhar com banco pelo que entendi, por segurança poderia criar uma hash ou token de verificação para que o unico a acessar o script seja o próprio cron.

Comment: Ainda tem alguma dúvida, poderíamos ajudar em mais alguma coisa, caso contrário poderia aceitar a resposta, clicando no "V" logo abaixo dos votos?